# What is a namespace and how is it implemented in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

I've heard the latest PHP has support for namespaces. I know variables defined in the global scope have *no* namespace, so how does one make a variable in a different namespace?

Is it just a way of categorising variables/functions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Namespaces are a programming language mechanism for organizing variables, functions and classes. PHP 5.3 adds support for namespaces, which I'll demonstrate in the following example:

Say you would like to combine two projects which use the same class name **User**, but have different implementations of each:

```
// Code for Project One (proj1.php)
<?php
  class User {
    protected $userId;
    public function getUserId() {
      return $this->userId;
    }
  }
  $user = new User;
  echo $user->getUserId();
?>

// Code for Project Two (proj2.php)
<?php
  class User {
    public $user_id;
  }
  $user = new User;
  echo $user->user_id;
?>

<?php
  // Combine the two projects
  require 'proj1.php';
  require 'proj2.php'; // Naming collision!
  $myUser = new User; // Which class to use?
?>
```

For versions of PHP less than 5.3, you would have to go through the trouble of changing the class name for all instances of the class **User** used by one of the projects to prevent a naming collision:

```
<?php
  class ProjectOne_User {
    // ...
  }
  $user = new ProjectOne_User; // Code in Project One has to be changed too
?>
```

For versions of PHP greater than or equal to 5.3, you can use namespaces when creating a project, by adding a namespace declaration:

```
<?php
  // Code for Project One (proj1.php)
  namespace ProjectOne;
  class User {
    // ...
  }
  $user = new User;
?>

<?php
  // Combine the two projects
  require 'proj1.php';

  use ProjectOne as One; // Declare namespace to use

  require 'proj2.php' // No collision!

  $user = new \One\User; // State which version of User class to use (using fully qualified namespace)

  echo $user->user_id; // Use ProjectOne implementation
?>
```

For more information:

- [PHP.net Namespaces](http://us.php.net/language.namespaces)
- [PHP Namespaces](http://blog.agoraproduction.com/index.php?/archives/47-PHP-Namespaces-Part-1-Basic-usage-gotchas.html)

Comment: Agreed. Very well done.

I just wish they went with a different delimiter between namespace and  class. :(

Comment: With the whole delimiter griping: it will work perfectly fine if you only use single quoted strings which I do for every string in php except for newlines

Comment: great example and explanation, I was completely lost on what namespaces do and php.net did not help at all but your answer does, thanks +1

Comment: Update: namespace delimiter happened to be \ instead of ::

Answer (score 3):

A [namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) allows you to organize code and gives you a way to encapsulate your items.

You can visualize namespaces as a file system uses directories to group related files.

Basically namespaces provide you a way in which to group related classes, functions and constants.

They also help to avoid name collisions between your PHP classes/functions/constants, and improve the code readability, avoiding extra-long class names.

Example namespace declaration:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject;

const CONNECT_OK = 1;
class Connection { /* ... */ }
function connect() { /* ... */  }

?>
```

Comment: So for a bunch of string helper functions, I should get them out of static functions in a class and do namespace String; function match() { } etc?

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces solve the problem of naming collisions when importing classes and functions from libraries.

Without namespaces, if you include two libraries which happen to define a function/class with the same name (ie, two libraries that both include a class called 'user'), it will fail.

With no namespace support in PHP, most libraries have taken to prefixing their function/class names with something that is likely to be unique, in an attempt to avoid name collisions.  The trouble is, this creates longer function or class names.

The example given [here](http://php100.wordpress.com/2007/08/17/namespaces-faq/) is of the exception class:

```
PEAR_Form_Loader_Validate_Table_Element_Validator_Exception.
```

You can import from a long namespace into your own local scope as an alias using the 'AS' keyword - a name you choose.  Thus, you can still have a short class name of your choice in your local scope.

The following applies an 'alias' called DbConnection to Zend::DB::Connection.

```
use Zend::DB::Connection as DbConnection
```

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are often used with libraries, the ability to reference the library code with 1 single *namespace* helps to not clobber up others that are already being used.